# Prevent Long String From Wrapping on Symbols

Tags: html, string, tags

I have a long string that contains a symbol but I need it to appear all on one line.

For example:

> ABunchOfCharsOnThisSide?ABunchOfCharsOnThisSide

Is there an HTML tag that will prevent this from wrapping at the symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me there happens no linebreak at the '&' symbol. But you can block every linebreak using the 'nobr' tag:

```
<nobr>ABunchOfCharsOnThisSide ABunchOfCharsOnThisSide</nobr>
```

That will even prevent spaces from wrapping.

Comment: Hmmm... yup should have been a "?" not a "&", however `<nobr>` doesn't seem to solve the problem when it actually is a "?".

Comment: also ? creates no linebreak for me

Comment: That's weird. I just tried editing the example by adding a ton of characters and it even breaks on "?". (Notably it did not break on "&".)

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, the latest version.

Comment: In chrome the ? breaks for me too, but the nobr prevents it from braking for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70709/discussion-between-tim-and-jonathan-mee).